# Why is it impossible to change content in css?

Tags: css, w3c

CSS2.1 pseudo-selectors such as `::after` and `::before` allows to add text content to the page. For example :

**CSS**

```css
 p:after { content:' Batman!' }
```

**HTML**

```html
<p>Na Na Na Na Na Na</p>
```

**Output in the browser**

```
Na Na Na Na Na Na Batman!
```

---

My question, with the same HTML source, is why this **piece of CSS**

```css
 p { content:'My hero is' }
 p:after { content:' Batman!' }
```

**doesn't outputs this**

```
My hero is Batman!
```

**but instead outputs this ?**

```
Na Na Na Na Na Na Batman!
```

---

The w3c spec on the content property : http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-content

---

**Answer** - I was looking at the CSS2.1 spec. The [CSS3 spec indicates](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#inserting3) it is possible even without `::after` and `::before` pseudo-selectors. But not every browser implements it.

- **Chrome 20.0.1132.57** : NO
- **Opera 12.00 r1467** : YES
- **Safari 5.1.7 (7534.57.2)** : NO
- **IE 8.0.7601** : NO (the CSS2 content property is not even implemented)

Comment: CSS is designed primarily to enable the separation of document content (written in HTML or a similar markup language) from document presentation, including elements such as the layout, colors, and fonts.

Comment: @pylover you must be mistaking. W3c is *the* reference. I think you meant w3school.

Comment: yes sorry, so i'll remove my comment

Comment: IE8 does implement the `content` property for `:before` and `:after` in CSS2. It just doesn't understand the CSS3 double-colon `::before` and `::after`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CSS 2.1 spec cited says: “Applies to:  :before and :after pseudo-elements”. This restriction has been relaxed in the draft for [CSS3 Generated and Replaced Content Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/), which is old (2003) and outdated but still partly implemented. Opera seems to support `content` for normal elements, except for the use of URL values (used to insert images), whereas Chrome and Safari do the same *only* for URL values. So you code actually works on Safari.

More widespread support is not very likely unless specification work on the module makes some progress. On the W3C [CSS module status page](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work.en.html), the module is in the “Rewriting” section, with the note “Severely outdated”.

Comment: exact ! I was on the css 2.1 spec, my bad.

Comment: Yeah. The next (2012) version of that module says "obsolete ... not actively maintained .. not to be used for implementations". It's a great shame, there was some cracking stuff in the 2003 version. We desperately need `::outside` to spare us all those wrapper `<div>`s.

Answer (score 5):

As specified by the spec `content:` is only usable together with the *pseudo-elements `:before` and `:after`, there isn't a better answer than that I'm afraid.

> #### [12.2 The 'content' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-content)
>
> > This property is used with the `:before` and `:after` *pseudo-elements* to
> >     generate content in a document.

---

However, if the question should be interpreted as *why aren't we allowed to add content anywhere we like using CSS?* The answer is only theoretical but as simple:

> CSS is not meant to be a way to provide new content, it is a way to format existing such.

> *"You are not supposed to change any content using CSS, there is not that much more than that to it. The `:before` and `:after` *pseudo-elements* have been discussed quite frequently because they break the barrier between formatting and content."* - refp

---

`:before`/`:after` are a great resources because they allow you to **format** your data in a way that wasn't possible before their appearance. Notice that I use the word "format" because I still consider it to be a *formatter*, not a data *generator*.

Coming up with a usable alternative that would still have a clear line between formatting and content would've been very hard (and frustrating), so this is (at least according to me) an acceptable middle-way which I can live it.

<sub>I must admit that I wasn't a big fan of the *pseudo-elements* in question when they first appeared.</sub>

Comment: I can understand it would a terrible, horrible, monstrous practice ; newbies would use it everywhere, etc.. I agree it's not what CSS is about. **Yet**, I see two reasons it would be a great features. 1/ CSS is not a way to provide new content, yet there is a `content` that allows to do exactly what CSS is not supposed to do. We could do the same as `content` but in HTML, which is the right way. 2/ It would be terribly useful for some one-every-blue-moon little hacks. For examples, I'm working on my blogger layout, and I'm frustrated because I can't change the content of hard-coded HTML.Right?

Comment: You are not supposed to change any content using CSS, there is not that much more than that to it. The `:before` and `:after` *pseudo-elements* have been discussed quite frequently because they break the barrier between formatting and content.

Comment: `content()` can be used, in Chrome 19+ (I think) to override the `src` of images: `content: url(http://example.com/path/to/image.png);`

Comment: I think it's very helpful the way it is. Take for example the **[micro clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)** which you can use without the need of a new element within your html structure. And I think there are other ways like getting text from a script, edit that part manually or use javascript to change a "hard-coded" HTML-part. But still a good question in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is possible to use `content` property directly on elements, and not on pseudo-elements only. Try

```
   p { content:'My hero is' }
```

in Opera and you'll see the result you wanted. The thing is other browsers don't support it yet.

A lot of other interesting things concerning generated content cat be found in [CSS3 Generated and Replaced Content Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/), but we'll have to wait a bit until browser venrors implement it.

Comment: exact too. I marked Jukka's answer as right, but you are also right (sorry about that)