# How do I use hover fading for "content" in CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, hover, fade

I have an image that changes sources when you hover over it. It works perfectly fine, except it doesn't fade at all.

Also, don't ask about the div/image caller. I used "#left:hover #logoLeft {" because I want the image to fade when you hover over the div it's in. It works, so just ignore it for now and pretend it says "logoleft:hover" or something.

The "left" id is unimportant for this, I don't want to post it to make it more confusing because it really has nothing to do with what I'm trying to achieve.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
<div id="left">
    <img id="logoLeft"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#logoLeft {
content:url("http://i.imgur.com/M8RPCkX.png");
height: 5em;
float: right;
margin-top: 2.5em;
transition: content 0.8s ease;
-moz-transition: content 0.8s ease;
-webkit-transition: content 0.8s ease;
}

#left:hover #logoLeft {
content:url("http://i.imgur.com/dlN4akx.png");
transition: content 0.8s ease;
-moz-transition: content 0.8s ease;
-webkit-transition: content 0.8s ease;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that generated content (the `::before`/`::after` pseudo-elements) can't be animated (even with CSS); though I have no recollection of where I learned that (though I'd suspect it was here on this site, and probably from an answer or comment from [Boltclock](http://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock)).

Comment: Read this  :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482591/why-is-it-impossible-to-change-content-in-css

Answer (score 0):

You can't transition content like that. The best way to achieve this is with two images (you could use a background-image but that isn't semantic).

```
<img id="logoLeft" src="//i.imgur.com/M8RPCkX.png" />
<img src="//i.imgur.com/dlN4akx.png" />
```

CSS:

```
#logoLeft + img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
#logoLeft:hover + img {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

The plus means "sibling after", you can replace it with an `id` if you want better browser support.

Comment: Given the use of generated content, I'd assume the OP's okay about not supporting any browser that doesn't implement the adjacent-sibling combinator.

Comment: @David That's good. Old browsers are evil and so are the people using them :P

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you even can have transitions for `content`.

I'd recommend to just fade `background-image` instead.